# Vue can't check the recently unchecked, checkbox even its binding

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2

I have a list of checkboxes, I want when I click on input 4th all previous boxes being checked and the rest unchecked.
I almost did it, but there is an issue that when I back to the those checked boxes and uncheck one of them, its still okay and the next being unchecked, but when again going forward and check another one from those unchecked the recently unchecked item being still unchecked and not changed.

here is the demo, and I think the GIF will describe my issue better.
[image]

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/j5dpkut8/1/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[0]" value="0" @change="printState(0)"> checked 0 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[1]" value="1" @change="printState(1)"> checked 1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[2]" value="2" @change="printState(2)"> checked 2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[3]" value="3" @change="printState(3)"> checked 3 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[4]" value="4" @change="printState(4)"> checked 4 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[5]" value="5" @change="printState(5)"> checked 5 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[6]" value="6" @change="printState(6)"> checked 6 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[7]" value="7" @change="printState(7)"> checked 7 <br>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    checked: [
      false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    printState(x) {
      this.checked = [
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
    ],
    for (let i = 1; i < this.checked.length; i++) {
        if (i <= x) {
          this.checked[i] = true;
        }
      }
     console.log(this.checked);
    
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: v-model should be bound to the value, in your case `checked` should be a list of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code change `change` handler into `click` handler and all will be **okey**.

**Or.**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: [
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
      { state: false },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    printState(x) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.checked.length; i++) {
        this.checked[i].state = i <= x ? true : false;
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(n, index) in checked" :key="index">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-model="n.state"
      @click="printState(index)"
    >

    <span>checked {{ index }} {{ n.state }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use the VUEXY template, it has the vs-checkbox that not supporting the click event, so I use the main input with type checkbox that working fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @TigranAbrahamyan mentioned, `@click` will fix it.  But here is a solution in very few lines that also uses `v-model` and `value` as intended and lets you easily adjust the number of boxes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({ num: 10, values: [] }),
  methods: {
    mark(index) {
      this.values = [...Array(index).keys()];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in num" :key="index-1">
     <input type="checkbox" v-model="values" :value="index-1" @click="mark(index-1)" />
  </div>
</div>
```